# Accessing remote URL on my local windows desktop machine

Tags: linux, windows, cloud, portforwarding

I am on a `windows desktop machine` and need to access a endpoint from a machine on `Oracle Cloud` securely .  The machine on the `Oracle Cloud` is a `Linux` machine and has both `public and private IP`.

```
        The URL is something like http://remotehostip:3000
```

Any way to port forward this URL to my local desktop machine so that I can access with something like `http://127.0.0.1:3000` . For such scenarios , will configuring `local port forwarding` on the `Linux machine` in the `Cloud` will help, something with a command as shown below
ssh -L 3000:remote_addr:3000 -i .ssh/id_prkey opc@]sshd_addr

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Have you tried that `ssh` command ?